# Truth and Lie Problem in Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A fair die is rolled once and the outcome is observed by person $A$. $A$ then reports the outcome to person $B$ and $B$ writes it on a paper slip which shows that $6$ appeared on the die. Given that $A$ speaks the truth $3$ out of $4$ times and $B$ writes the truth (i.e, what A told him) $7$ out of $8$ times, what is the probability that $6$ actually appeared on the die? Given that when $A$ and $B$ are lying they tell or write a random number from $1$ to $6$ other than the one which they have observed (in case of $A$) or been told (in case of $B$).
Since I'm not that good at math so I made a code that imitated the given scenario and iterated it a billion times. The probability, thus obtained, approached $0.1107$. But I want to solve this problem mathematically.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to tell us how you started to solve the problem and where you are stuck.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know how to start. Perhaps a little guidance might help.

Comment: Perhaps start with rolling a die?

Comment: Actually we need to know if $A$ or $B$ lie *how* do they determine what they will lie.  If $A$ told his something other than $6$ and $B$ lied,  does $B$ lie by picking a value that isnt $6$ at random?  Does $B$ lie by always answering $6$?  Does $B$ lie by always adding one  more to the truth?  Does $B$ ever lie by saying "seven" or "green elephant"?  Does $B$ ever "lie" by picking a number at random and it turns out by pure chance to actually be true?

Answer (score 3):

Let $B$ be the event that $B$ writes $6$ and $R$ be the event that a $6$ was rolled.  We need to calculate $$P(R|B)=\frac{P(R\cap B)}{P(B)}$$

---

Let $p$ be the probability that $A$ tells the truth. The probability that $B$ is told that a $6$ was rolled is $$\frac16p+\frac56(1-p)\left(\frac15\right)=\frac16p+\frac16(1-p)=\frac16$$ since either a $6$ is rolled and $A$ tells the truth or a $6$ is not rolled, $A$ lies, and $A$ chooses to report a $6$ among all possible false values.  Therefore, the probability that $A$ reports $6$ to $B$ is $\frac16$ -- independent of the probability that $A$ tells the truth.

Obviously, the same calculation applies to the second half.  There is a $\frac16$ probability that $B$ is told to write a 6 and that is the probability that he will write a $6$ independently of how trustworthy he is.  Thus, $P(B)=\frac16$.

---

Now we need to find $P(R\cap B)$, the probability that both a $6$ was rolled *and* written.  For this, we do need the trustworthiness probabilities.  To have a 6 rolled and written, we need a six rolled AND (either A and B both tell the truth or A and B both lie and B chooses to write 6), which is $$\frac16(\frac34\cdot\frac78+\frac14\cdot\frac18\cdot\frac15)=\frac{53}{480}$$

Thus $$P(R|B)=\frac{{53}/{480}}{1/6}=\frac{53}{80}$$

Comment: This argument shows that the process starting with a roll will produce each of the six numbers on the paper with probability $1/6$, independent of the probabilities that A and B are truthful. But the conditional probability that a $6$ was rolled given that a $6$ is on the paper does depend on the truthfulness of the reporters. As @NuclearWang comments above, if they are both reliable then that conditional probability is $1$.

Comment: @EthanBolker I believe I have answered the question correctly now.

Comment: Yes, under the natural assumption that lies are chosen randomly from the false possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Nefore you look at the paper the probability that a $6$ was rolled is $1/6$.

If you want to see how that probability changes when you know  B wrote $6$, draw a tree showing all the scenarios, with probabilities

```
roll 6 (probability 1/6)
   A reports 6 (probability 3/4)
       B writes 6
       B writes 1-5
   A reports 1-5 (probability 1/4)
       B writes 6
       B writes 1-5
roll 1-5 (probability 5/6)
   A reports 1-5 truthfully (probability 3/4)
       B writes 6
       B writes 1-5
   A reports 1-5 when lying (probability ??)
       B writes 6
       B writes 1-5
   A reports 6 when lying (probability ??)
       B writes 6
       B writes 1-5
```

Finish the tree, then multiply the probabilities down each branch  and sum the ones where B wrote $6$. Find the fraction of that when you sum the paths that start with a roll of $6. You will have to decide what happens when A or B lies.

Comment: Your second sentence can't be correct in general - if A and B always tell the truth, if B says a 6 was rolled, then the probability a 6 was rolled is 1. The probability that a 6 was rolled is not independent of what A says and B writes in every probability configuration. Is the argument that the numbers just happen to work out to make their statements irrelevant?

Comment: @NuclearWang I agree that my first paragraph is clumsy. Indeed it's wrong unless you read what I meant rather than what I said. I will edit, thanks.

Comment: Right, the probability of any fair die roll being a 6 is 1/6. But the question is not what's the odds A rolled a 6 without any other information - it's what's the odds A rolled a 6, *knowing that B wrote it was a 6*. If A and B are both truth-tellers, that probability is 1. If A is a truth-teller and B is a liar, that probability is 0. I'm sure there are intermediate values that work out such that the conditional probability is in fact 1/6, but it's far from clear if this is one of those special truthfulness probability configurations.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
d6&A&B&count\\
\hline
1-5&T&T&105\\
\hline
1-5&T&F&15\\
\hline
1-5&F&T&35\\
\hline
1-5&F&F&5\\
\hline
6&T&T&21\\
\hline
6&T&F&3\\
\hline
6&F&T&7\\
\hline
6&F&F&1\\
\hline
\end{array}

I have assumed that if B hears a $1-5$, he writes a $6$.

The cases we are interested in are $15+35+21+1=72$. Of these, a six was thrown for $21+1=22$ of the cases.

Therefore the probability that B writes $6$ AND a six was thrown is $\frac{11}{36}$.